# Mapping Network Drives In Mac Using BASH

Tags: linux, bash, macos

On Windows I created a simple script to connect to different shares on a network drive due to issues with our VPN not mapping the drives automatically. Here is what the script sort of looks like.

```
@ECHO OFF
net use a: \\someserver1\share1\%username% << each users personal share 
net use b: \\someserver2\share2 
net use c: \\someserver3\share3
```

My goal is to due to same for our new Mac users however I am unsure of how to accomplish this. I have some minor linux experience so I started to read the man page for "mount" but I am a bit unsure how to proceed exactly.

Also I do not want to use any sort of IP addresses of the devices for security purposes as it seems most suggestions seem to map using IP's.

Comment: Try `osascript -e "try" -e "mount volume \"smb://username@someserver/share1\username\"" -e "end try"`

Comment: but, not a programming question; more of a superuser question.